# Configure XFCE in Debian etch (4.0)

Tags: debian, virtualbox, virtual-machine

i am currently installing Debian Etch as a Virtual Machine with Virtual Box (the host is a windows 10). I used an iso (from debian website) to install it, but it seems that no desktop environment was set (i think the related packages were not in the iso). So i'm trying to install xfce with shell, simply using "apt-get install xfce4" and "apt-get install xfce4-tools" (or something like that, not sure of the name of this package anymore)

Of course, since i'm using debian etch, my sources.list link on debian-archives dist etch. So i won't have the latest version; but i only want some desktop environment for etch.

The install wrent well, but i got an error when i try to launch it with startx:

```
Error: No device detected
Fatal error: 
no screens found.
XIO: fatal IO error 104 (connection reset by peer) on X server ":0.0"
    after 0 requests (0 known processed) with 0 events remaining.
```

I've made some research online, and it seems that it may come from the config file. I'm pretty sure mine is not correct, because i'm in a VM. In particular, i have those lines, which seems wrong to me:

```
Section "Device":
    Identifier     "Carte vidéo générique"  //translate to generic graphic card
    Driver         "nv"
    BusID          "PCI:0:2:0"
Endsection

Section "Monitor":
    Identifier    "Ecran générique"  // translate to generic screen
    Option        "DPMS"
    HorizSync     28-49
    VertRefresh   43-72
EndSection

Section "Screen":
    Identifier    "Default Screen"
    Device        "Carte vidéo générique"
    Monitor       "Ecran générique"
    DefaultDepth   24
/* different display subsection....*/
EndSection

Section "ServerLayout":
    Identifier    "Default Layout"
    Screen        "Default Screen"
    InputDevice   "Generic keyboard"
    InputDevice   "Configured Mouse"
    InputDevice   "Synaptic Touchpad"
EndSection

Section "DRI": 
    Mode    0666
EndSection
```

(No idea what the DRI is. And of course i have other sections before that.)

I think that, since i'm in a VM, i do not have "real" graphic card or screen, and then it's set as "genereci graphic card" and "generic screen", and that's not a good configuration. However, i have no idea how to configure this so that it works. And i'm a bit tired of the shell, i really would like to have a desktop environment.

i've tried to desinstall xfce and install gnome instead, but got exactly the same bug. Since Xfce is lighter, i would like to keep this one. However, if you have a working solution for gnome, i would happily take it; anything but no more shell, please!

PS: i also have this annoying message in shell:

```
ata1 : spurious interrupt (irq_stat 0x8 active_tag -84118995 sactive 0x0)
```

Thinks it's realted to the fact that i use the mouse and keyboard out of the vm and it somehow still recognise it wrong. But that's juste a thought. It seems to appear randomly, even when i'm not doing anything :/ maybe it's related to my problem, then.

Comment: Etch has been end of life for nearly 10 years.

Comment: i know. This particular point was not my choice. Of course i would prefer to work on a more recent debian version, but as a newbie i have to do as asked. so debian etch it is.